# Mapping keyboard: at most primitive level

Tags: key-mapping

When I was using a comfort curve keyboard which had media keys, those keys worked 
as media keys in X ( with different users), in single-user mode and in multiuser-mode without X.

Then I switched to an RK-9000, which is a quite excellent keyboard but has no media keys. ;...(

But there are a few keys I never use. Scroll lock comes to mind as well as pause. So things like scrl-lck-cursor-up can be mapped to media on/off.

I'm vaguely aware of a technique using xev/xmodmap but my understanding is that that technique is done at the X level, and is assigned to a particular user.

I would like a more primitive way of redefining keys. Two things that occur to me are:

1) The way tty's are mapped to ALT-CTL-Fn ( in my distro, LMDE, I believe this is true of Fedora as well but might vary with distros ). This way works whether or not X is started.
2) When installing a distro, you are generally  asked to choose a keyboard.

Once you make the choice, it is my understanding that some keymapping is assigned. Uniformly at all levels and will will in multiuser X-less modes and single user modes.

So how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In the Debian-derived distros the console and X key mappings are now both set up in /etc/default/keyboard.  See http://wiki.debian.org/Keyboard.

Before that both X and console key mappings were set up separately each with its own respective set of utilities and configuration files.  See http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/Keyboard-and-Console-HOWTO.